# Unable to update apps in AppCenter

Tags: updates, appcenter

I've searched on the forum but I couldn't seem to find an issue similar to mine: whenever I click un the update button (or update all) in the update tab of App Center (either for apps or system updates), the button changes for a milisecond and then comes back to normal with nothing else happening.

Any ideas on what's going on?

Thanks in advance,

Jesus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try updating from terminal this time:

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
```

Then go back to Appcenter and check if everything is updated. Next time there's an update it should work as normal.

Comment: I already did, but still same behaviour happening :/

Comment: Are you using elementary OS Loki? Did you add any repository?

Comment: Yes it is Loki, and yes, I've added a few lately. Could they be causing any problems? Is there any way to see the repositories I've added? (I can't remember the name of the ones I added lately :/ ) Thanks!

Comment: All the PPAs you add are inside `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/ `.. If you've added the elementary daily PPA (unstable) then your issue is a bug and you should post it in launchpad. I don't think any other PPA would cause this kind of bug... maybe a PPA that doesn't update (if that's the case you should get some error in `apt update` )

Comment: I do have `elementary-os-ubuntu-daily-xenial.list`
Might that one be the one causing problems?

Comment: Yes. Maybe your installed loki from the beta version or maybe you've added this PPA. Anyway, to remove it you could do `sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:elementary-os/daily` but i recommend to `sudo apt install ppa-purge` instead so that it downgrades the packages `sudo ppa-purge ppa:elementary-os/daily `

Comment: Well, I didn't have to, today it worked on its own, so.. problem solved! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Well it's solved because the elementary team updated AppCenter. But remember that you are using a beta  version of elementary OS, so you may find another similar bugs in the future.